# Telerik Winforms ChartView: How to choose a different background color for a chart label

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using Telerik WinForms, the lastest version.
I have pie chart, 1 series with 4 datapoint and assigned a custom palette with 4 colors (red, green, orange and blue), only first fill color, no additional setting. This works well so far. I also want to display the according labels. This works also, but all the labels have the same background color as it corrensponding data point/segment. That I would like to change.
When I don't use any palette than each segement has its own color but the all the labels have white background.

Is there a way to change the background color of the labels?

There is no way for me to switch any other than winforms.

Also if there is no way of doing it, I would like to know.

If you need more information and/or screenshots please ask, it would be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in Telerik forum and they provided a working answer. It can be found here http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/chartview/how-to-choose-a-different-background-color-for-a-chart-label.aspx